# Access Blackberry "Send To" Menu

Tags: blackberry, java-me, menu

I'd like access the "Send To" menu, that features all the, apparently registered recipients of that action.
On my phone, this menu contains
* Email
* PIN
* SMS
* MMS
* BBM Contact

How can I do this from Java?

EDIT: For BB OS 4.0+ platforms.

Here's what I've used so far by overriding the getMenu method.
At getAppName() in the simulator,  I've been getting values like:
* net_rim_bb_sendusingbluetoothapp
* net_rim_bb_sendasemailapp
* net_rim_bb_sendtomessengercontactapp

So I expect I'll use some String.replace() with that, but when I use the

```
reg.invoke(inv);
```

call below, though the mail application starts up, no arguments like subject or message content appears.  How should I go about setting that?

Also, for setData(), I just pass in a random string.  (I'm pretty sure that's where I should be setting more meaningful stuff, but I don't know what).

```
public Menu getMenu(int instance) {
        Menu menu =  super.getMenu(instance);

        final Registry reg = Registry.getRegistry(CLASSNAME);
        ContentHandler[] handles = reg.forAction(ContentHandler.ACTION_SEND);


        for (int i=0;i<handles.length;i++)
        {
            String name = handles[i].getAppName();
            final Invocation inv = new Invocation();
            inv.setURL(sendToUrl);
            inv.setResponseRequired(false);
            inv.setType(handles[i].getType(0));
            inv.setID(handles[i].getID());
            inv.setData(sendToUrl.getBytes());
            inv.setAction(handles[i].getAction(0));
            inv.setArgs(new String[]{sendToUrl});



            MenuItem mit = new MenuItem(new StringProvider(name), i, i)
            {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        reg.invoke(inv);
                        //inv.open(false);
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                }
            };

            //ContentHandlerMenu contentHandlerMenu 
            //= new ContentHandlerMenu(inv, reg, "Send to "+ name, i,i);

            //menu.add(contentHandlerMenu);
            menu.add(mit);
        }
        return menu;

    }
```

Comment: @Vic's answer is the best you're going to get.  RIM did not expose the Send menu until OS 7.

Comment: @Scott, looking at the twitter for blackberry app (OS 5.0), that "Send To" menu looks like something gotten from the the OS.  If not, twitter did a good job.

Comment: The Twitter app for BlackBerry (at least the one that is just called "Twitter") is actually developed by RIM ;)  My guess is they can do pretty much whatever they want.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you need? [Send Menu API](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29190/Send_Menu_API_1633998_11.jsp). I found it searching in Google... It was not too difficult.